# Simple shortcode $id+$title with small html

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a simple need to put a shortcode at the end of my articles on wordpress with the post id and post title.
I want to add a (ref:) in front of $id and enclose it all in h4

the desired result look like this

```
<h4 ref: 123 this is my first post <h4>
```

I'm having a hard time getting the logic of how to do it

my shortcode

```
function post_id_title( ){
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $result = $id . $title ;
   return $result;
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'post_id_title' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this since you got the hardest part right.

```php
function post_id_title( ){
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $result = "<h4>ref: $id $title</h4>";
   return $result;
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'post_id_title' );
```

Comment: thank you very much for the comment, the code works well I did not know since I did not test 